# x264 process stops working no matter on anything

Tags: .net, asp.net, process, mp4, h.264

i have made my video encoder. well very simple one and my process stops working after it gets to certain percent.

Is there anything i could do to make it work? Is there some memory limitation?
Could i run it somehow different?

Comment: Without the output from the encoder it is almost impossible to help you.  Record the x264 output and post here.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due to the default timeout settings?

i.e. In your web.config file, adjust as follows (or with a higher value):

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="900" maxRequestLength="30000" />
```

Comment: No placed <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600000" /> and no help. Process in task manager takes up 62mb of memory. Maybe it needs more. And it allways needs same memory. I am running the website localy in vs so i guess it should not be limited with memory. I am thinking to make windows app and to see how it will beheve there.